# how to concatenate with a flatten layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, flatten

I would like to flatten an input before concatenation like below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    CategoryEncoding,
    Concatenate,
    Dense,
    Discretization,
    Embedding,
    Flatten,
    Input,
)
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import HashedCrossing


dnn_hidden_units = [32, 8]
NBUCKETS = 16

latbuckets = np.linspace(start=38.0, stop=42.0, num=NBUCKETS).tolist()
lonbuckets = np.linspace(start=-76.0, stop=-72.0, num=NBUCKETS).tolist()

# Bucketization with Discretization layer
plon = Discretization(lonbuckets, name="plon_bkt")(inputs["pickup_longitude"])
plat = Discretization(latbuckets, name="plat_bkt")(inputs["pickup_latitude"])
dlon = Discretization(lonbuckets, name="dlon_bkt")(inputs["dropoff_longitude"])
dlat = Discretization(latbuckets, name="dlat_bkt")(inputs["dropoff_latitude"])

# Feature Cross with HashedCrossing layer
p_fc = HashedCrossing(num_bins=NBUCKETS * NBUCKETS, name="p_fc")((plon, plat))
d_fc = HashedCrossing(num_bins=NBUCKETS * NBUCKETS, name="d_fc")((dlon, dlat))
pd_fc = HashedCrossing(num_bins=NBUCKETS**4, name="pd_fc")((p_fc, d_fc))

# Embedding with Embedding layer
pd_embed = Embedding(input_dim=NBUCKETS**4, output_dim=10, name="pd_embed")(
    pd_fc
)

unk = Concatenate(axis=1)([pd_embed])

# Concatenate and define inputs for deep network
deep = Concatenate(name="deep_input",axis=0)(
    [   
        inputs["pickup_longitude"],
        inputs["pickup_latitude"],
        inputs["dropoff_longitude"],
        inputs["dropoff_latitude"],
        Flatten(name="flatten_embedding")(pd_embed),
    ]
)
```

I am getting the following error at the conatenate layer.

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
> except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None,),
> (None,), (None,), (None,), (None, 10)]

I understand that (None,10) should be (None*10) or just (None) but I am not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

The concatenate layer takes input as a list of tensors, all of the same shape except for the concatenation axis, and returns a single tensor that is the concatenation of all inputs.

In the error you have mentioned above says that you try to concatenate 2 different shapes None(has an unknown number of dimensions, and an unknown size in all dimensions) and None,10 ( has a known number of dimensions, and an unknown size for one or more dimension).

For example i have to concatenate 2 tensors a and b (a,b has to be the same size)

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.random.uniform([2,3])
b=tf.random.uniform([2,3])
tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=0)([a.numpy(), b.numpy()])

output:<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.5595623 , 0.07109773, 0.646863  ],
   [0.1997714 , 0.6131079 , 0.03418195],
   [0.40428162, 0.94192684, 0.10390592],
   [0.72463846, 0.3348019 , 0.95906615]], dtype=float32)>
```

If a and b are of different shape it will produce an error

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Thank You.